# Realplayer breaking in Firefox when referencing css files from a server

Tags: realplayer

Having a problem with Real player embed working when CSS files are referenced from a server location when running the 'test' simplified html webpage locally to replicate the scenario.

Here is the code which **Doesn't** work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>    
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Realplayer Test</title>

    <link href="http://domain.com/Content/Styles/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
</head>
<body>    
    <object id="media"
    classid="clsid:CFCDAA03-8BE4-11cf-B84B-0020AFBBCCFA"
    height=360 width=640>
    <param name="controls" value="ImageWindow">
    <param name="console" value="Clip1">
    <param name="autostart" value="true">
    <param name="src" value="rtsp://domain.com/mediatemp/93088761_hi.rm">
    <embed src="rtsp://domain.com/mediatemp/93088761_hi.rm" console="Clip1" controls="ImageWindow"
    height="360" width="640" type="audio/x-pn-realaudio-plugin" autostart="true">
    </object>
    <br>
    <object id="media"
    classid="CLSID:CFCDAA03-8BE4-11CF-B84B-0020AFBBCCFA" width="320"
    height="100">
    <param name="src" value="rtsp://domain.com/mediatemp/93088761_hi.rm">
    <param name="console" value="Clip1">
    <param name="controls" value="All">
    <param name="AutoStart" value="true">
    <embed controls="All" console="Clip1"
    type="audio/x-pn-realaudio-plugin" src="rtsp://domain.com/mediatemp/93088761_hi.rm"
    width="640" height="100" autostart="true">
    </object>
</body>
</html>
```

This is what gets displayed in the browser:
[image: realerror]

Here is the code what **does** work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>    
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Realplayer Test</title>

    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>    
    <object id="media"
    classid="clsid:CFCDAA03-8BE4-11cf-B84B-0020AFBBCCFA"
    height=360 width=640>
    <param name="controls" value="ImageWindow">
    <param name="console" value="Clip1">
    <param name="autostart" value="true">
    <param name="src" value="rtsp://domain.com/mediatemp/93088761_hi.rm">
    <embed src="rtsp://domain.com/mediatemp/93088761_hi.rm" console="Clip1" controls="ImageWindow"
    height="360" width="640" type="audio/x-pn-realaudio-plugin" autostart="true">
    </object>
    <br>
    <object id="media"
    classid="CLSID:CFCDAA03-8BE4-11CF-B84B-0020AFBBCCFA" width="320"
    height="100">
    <param name="src" value="rtsp://domain.com/mediatemp/93088761_hi.rm">
    <param name="console" value="Clip1">
    <param name="controls" value="All">
    <param name="AutoStart" value="true">
    <embed controls="All" console="Clip1"
    type="audio/x-pn-realaudio-plugin" src="rtsp://domain.com/mediatemp/93088761_hi.rm"
    width="640" height="100" autostart="true">
    </object>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: working]

Style.css is the same CSS markup in both instances. Any ideas why the player would stop working when the CSS file is referenced from a url location. I have uploaded the styles.css files to multiple servers and the same issue happens still.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Browser security would be the thing to look at, since programmatically loading CSS from a URL is now a security risk:

> Starting with Firefox 23, Firefox blocks active mixed content by default. This follows a practice adopted by Internet Explorer (since version 9) and Chrome.
>
> If your website delivers HTTPS pages, all content (image, script, video, stylesheet, iframe, font...) delivered via HTTP will be blocked by default. Consequently, your website may appear broken to users (if images don't load, etc.).
>
> Note that since mixed content blocking already happens in Chrome and Internet Explorer, it is very likely that if your website works in these browsers, it will work equally well in Firefox with mixed content blocking.

**References**

- [Mixed Content Blocking Enabled in Firefox 23](https://blog.mozilla.org/tanvi/2013/04/10/mixed-content-blocking-enabled-in-firefox-23/)